# How to query with multiple expressions in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a list of users with `name`, `age` and `country`.

Now I want to query this user list with the following queries.

1. Search by name only.
2. Search by name and country both

something I tried earlier but failed to get the desired results.

```
users.find({
            $and: [
             { name: name },
             { country: country },
            ],
           })
```

When I search with `name` only, I do not get any result because `country` is null in my query.

It works fine when I pass `name` and `country` both in the query.

I need to understand how to query with null values if being passed in expressions.

Comment: why dont you use `$or` instead of `$and`

Comment: I did use $or, in that case it will look for all records with name (or) also with country. I want to search for name (and) country

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a variable and put the condition,

```
let match = {};
if (name) match.name = name;
if (country) match.country = country;

users.find(match);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an if statement to query depending on what information you have

```
if(name && country){
    users.find({
            $and: [
             { name: name },
             { country: country }
            ]
           })
} else if (name){
    users.find({name: name})
}
```